# Create own column in View and count also non existing values

Tags: sql, impala

I have a view that outputs, among other things, a status based on other statuses in the base table and an ID.

```
CREATE VIEW MY_TEST 
AS
    SELECT
        ID,
        Time,
        CASE 
            WHEN status = '´Something' THEN 'New'
            WHEN status = '´Something1' THEN 'Old'
            WHEN status = '´Something2' THEN 'Current'
            WHEN status = '´Something3' THEN 'Next'
            WHEN status = '´Something4' THEN 'Now'
        END AS my_status
    FROM 
        table;
```

Table data:

| ID | Time | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15:00 | Something |
| 2 | 15:00 | Something |
| 3 | 16:00 | Something1 |
| 4 | 16:00 | Something |
| 5 | 15:00 | Something2 |

I want to count the IDs of the view and group them by `my_status`. This works fine so far.

```
SELECT
    Time,
    COUNT(ID) count_,
    my_status
FROM 
    my_test
GROUP BY 
    my_status, time;
```

Output:

| COUNT_ | Time | MY_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 15:00 | New |
| 1 | 15:00 | Current |
| 1 | 16:00 | Old |
| 1 | 16:00 | New |

Desired output should like:

| COUNT_ | Time | MY_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 15:00 | New |
| 1 | 15:00 | Current |
| 0 | 15:00 | Next |
| 0 | 15:00 | Now |
| 1 | 16:00 | Old |
| 1 | 16:00 | New |
| 0 | 16:00 | Next |
| 0 | 16:00 | Now |

But how is it possible to output all possible `my_status` values (which could be) and fill them with 0 even if the my_status values are not there?

- Where do I have to create the `my_status` values?
- What must the query look like afterwards?

**Information:**
The possible my_status values are not stored in any other table, therefore I can not use it like JOIN this table. This should be flexible.

Comment: Please include sample input and output data which helps to explain your question.

Comment: OUTER JOIN a query/table returning _all possible my_status values_.

Comment: @jarlh I don't have the option with a table where the stati are saved in.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a _base table_. It can be a cte, derived table, VALUES etc. (depending on what Impala functionality offers.)

Answer (score 1):

An ideal solution here would be to create a new status table which contains each status value and its text mapping.  Then, join this table to your table and aggregate by status:

```
Table: Status
status     | label
Something  | New
Something1 | Old
Something2 | Current
Something3 | Next
Something4 | Now
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT s.label, COUNT(t.status) AS cnt
FROM Status s
LEFT JOIN my_status t
    ON t.status = s.status
GROUP BY s.label;
```

The `Status` table could be inline inside a CTE or a subquery:

```sql
WITH Status AS (
    SELECT 'Something' AS status, 'New' AS label UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Something1', 'Old'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Something2', 'Current' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Something3', 'Next'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Something4', 'Now'
)

SELECT s.label, COUNT(t.status) AS cnt
FROM Status s
LEFT JOIN my_status t
    ON t.status = s.status
GROUP BY s.label;
```

Comment: Yes this would be the best solution, but it is not possible to create this table. So is there a way how to do it without creating such reference table?

Comment: Sure, you could inline this reference table in a CTE or subquery and join using it.

Comment: Ok than can you give me an example how to do it

Comment: Thank you. It is working in base, but I don't get the output I need. I will update the question again, maybe it is bringing light into dark.